# Terraform deployment of Azure Container Registry with Network Rule Set

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure, azure-container-registry

We are deploying AKS and ACR in separate virtual networks in Azure using Terraform. In order to allow connections from AKS, we need to set ACR's `network_rule_set` in creation. However since the AKS doesn't yet exist, the network rule set cannot be defined. We could theoretically use local-exec and Azure CLI but this doesn't affect the Terraform state and the network rule set is wiped in any subsequent runs. How can we overcome this kind of situation?

Comment: I dont really see a problem here, you dont need a vnet for acr, you can precreate the vnet for AKS in the same terraform configuration and grant that access to the ACR

Comment: Does the answer solve your problem? Or need more help? Give updates!

Answer (score 0):

First, the ACR does not need a virtual network, so you do not need to configure the virtual network for it. You just need to configure the virtual network for the AKS.

Second, you can create the virtual network and subnet yourself and create the AKS cluster in the subnet. You can use the [`vnet_subnet_id`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/kubernetes_cluster.html#vnet_subnet_id) to set it.

Finally, you can create the ACr and set the `network_rule_set` with the virtual network that you create in the Terraform. Don't worry about the sequence of resource creation, Terraform will sort all the resources correctly.